# self not defined

Tags: python

Code:

```py
class User():
    """A class to describe typical user and it's info."""

    def __init__(self, username, password, first_name, age, birthdate, last_name, middle_name=None, location='', email=''):
        """Initialize first and last names, age, birthdate and location(optional)"""
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.email = email
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.middle_name = middle_name
        self.age = age
        self.birthdate = birthdate

    def confirm_user(self):
        enter_use = "Please enter your username."
        use = input(enter_use)
        if use == user_1(use):
            enter_password = "Please enter your password."
            password = input(enter_password)
            if password == user_1(password):
                logged_in_user = user_1
                print('Login successful.')
        elif use == user_2(use):
            enter_password = "Please enter your password."
            password = input(enter_password)
            if password == user_2(password):
                logged_in_user = user_2
                print('Login successful.')
        elif use == user_3(use):
            enter_password = "Please enter your password."
            password = input(enter_password)
            if password == user_3(password):
                logged_in_user = user_3
                print('Login successful.')
        elif use != user_1(username) and user_2(username) and user_3(username):
            print('Invalid username. If you wish to make an account that uses that username, please sign up.')
        elif password != user_1(password) and user_2(password) and user_3(password):
            print('Invalid password. If you wish to make an account that uses that password, please sign up.')
        else:
            print('Invalid username and password. If you wish to make an account that uses that password and username, please sign up.')
        
    def greet_user(self):
        full_name = self.first_name + self.middle_name + self.last_name
        print('Welcome, ' + (str(full_name.title())) + '!')
        
    def post(self):
        """Defining the action of a user posting a message on a website."""
        ask = "\nDo you want to post a message?\n(y/n)"
        ans = input(ask)

        if ans == 'y':
            post_what = "\nPlease enter what you want to post:"
            post_this = input(post_what)
            print(logged_in_user + ':' + post_this)
        else:
            print('You are welcome to post a message next time!')
        
user_1 = User('matty1234*', 'matjersey12341234', 'matjersey@hotmail.com', 'mat', 'jersey', 37, '1983/12/31', 'Canada, Ontario, Toronto, Scarborough, Brimley Road')
user_2 = User('<wdwith92>', 'asf2vel', 'sarah_elens@hotmail.com', 'sarah', 'elens', 39, '1981/10/30', 'Canada, Ontario, Toronto, Scarborough, Brimley Road')
user_3 = User('alice&wonderland', 'jonny374', 'jon', 7, '2012/12/24', 'lee', 'elens', 'Canada, Ontario, Toronto, Scarborough, Brimley Road')
users = [user_1, user_2, user_3]

for user in users:
    self.confirm_user()
    self.greet_user()
    self.post()
```

What is wrong???

I've basically written code that let's you login. It checks if the username and password is some user's username and password, if true, the program posts a greeting an then it asks you if you want to post a message. Yes: you enter what you want to write and python prints your username followed by your message. No: prints that you are welcome to post a message next time. Now, back to the first login question: if false, it print a message sayin that you have entered a invalid username or password.

Error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\di\OneDrive\文档\alice_coding_stuff\python files\User.py", line 66, in <module>
    self.confirm_user()
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uh.. that looks like a typo:

```py
for user in users:
    user.confirm_user()
    user.greet_user()
    user.post()
```

Comment: mind adding an explanation about within an instance method vs just using an object from outside?

Comment: Sorry, @SuperStormer, I don't know what you mean.